# Grunt JSHint Multiple Tasks Problems

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am having issues setting up JSHint to run multiple tasks. Here is what I have:

```
 jshint: {
      app: {
        files: [
            'web/**/*.js',
            '!web/app.js',
            '!web/lib/**',
            '!web/build/**'
        ],
        options: {
            // Just let the templates do whatever they want when compiled
            ignores: ['web/templates/*.js'],
            // options here to override JSHint defaults
            loopfunc: true,
            newcap: false,
            reporter: require('jshint-stylish'),
            globals: {
                jQuery: true,
                gadget: true
            }
        }
      },
      test: {
        files: [
            'web/**/*.js',
            '!web/app.js',
            '!web/lib/**',
            '!web/build/**'
        ],
        options: {
            // just let the templates do whatever they want when compiled
            ignores: ['web/templates/*.js'],
            reporter: require('jshint-stylish'),
            jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
        }
      }

 }
```

When I try to run `grunt jshint:app` or `grunt jshint:test`, I get errors that there is no task for either of those.

Thank you for your help if you see anything that I have missed.

Comment: did you register the task grunt-contrib-jshint? Can we see more of your grunt file?

Comment: Is this task inside a `grunt.initConfig({`? Maybe you need to post all the file

Comment: yes I have the task registered. So with the task registered, I figured I could just run one of those tasks and it would work. The error that I am getting is: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'loadnpmtasks' ??

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
```

to your grunt file

Comment: thank you. Looks like when I opened the file in vim it somehow lower cased my whole file